# Is it possible to find the moment of inertia at a particular point in a body with uniform mass distribution

Tags: rotational-dynamics, torque, moment-of-inertia

Can i find the moment of inertia at P if the axis is XX'(passes through the COM) or is the moment of inertia same at every point ???

[image]

Comment: The axis doesn't seem to pass through P

Comment: [Parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem)

Comment: @JohnRennie p is not the new axis of rotation

Comment: @JohnRennie xx' is still the axis of rotation

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to define moment of inertia about a point only

Comment: @MeetLalwani the moment of inertia is defined relative to an axis i.e. relative to $XX'$. It is meaningless to ask what the MOI is at the point $P$.

Comment: @MeetLalwani please read and understand the definition and meaning of moment of inertia, your doubt will be solved. The you need to define which bodie's moment of inertia you want to calculate, the ehtire rigid rod, or the point P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of inertia of the whole stick is determined by adding up (or integrating) the moments of inertia of al points on the stick with mass dm where sum of all dm equals m, the moment of inertia of a pointmass depends on its distance from the axes.